# Make image positioned on another container

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

My HTML is like this

```
    <div class="container-panel">
  <div class="inner-bannerbg">
  </div>
  <div class="home-second-holder">
    <div class="wrapper clearfix">
      <ul class="service-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="/qw/privat/" class="inner-nav inner-nav01 active">Privat</a>
          <span class="arrow01"></span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/qw/lorem/" class="inner-nav inner-nav02">Lorem</a>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/qw/some/" class="inner-nav inner-nav03">some</a>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/qw/numquam/" class="inner-nav inner-nav04">numquam</a>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/loesninger/ducimus/" class="inner-nav inner-nav05">ducimus</a>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/qw/2/" class="inner-nav inner-nav06">2</a>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/qw/4/" class="inner-nav inner-nav07">4</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="private-block">
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see there is a `span` inside first `li` .And an arrow image is attached to this `span` .
CSS for this span

```
    ul.service-menu li span.arrow01 {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 44px;
background: url(../Images/active-arrow01.png) no-repeat center bottom;
left: 0;
bottom: -161px;
}
```

Using this css I have arranged arrow to come direct under current active `li` . and position right above my `private-block` `div`.This positioning completely relying on my CSS

```
 bottom: -161px;
```

The problem is that as the number of `li` is dynamic some times an extra row may come and break my style.If number of `li` grows there will be extra rows present and that will make this arrow align wrong.To get more in to this I will post the screen here
[image]
Can any one help me to make a css that will make arrow reside on top of `private-block` `div` ,neverthles how many rows are there.

Comment: Read http://davidwalsh.name/css-triangles and http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Comment: @TusharGupta My problem is with positioning the arrow correctly where I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the arrow as the pseudo element of the `.wrapper`. Don't forget to set `position: relative` for the `.wrapper`:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper::after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 44px;
    content: url(../Images/active-arrow01.png); /* notice that the image becomes the "content" of the pseudo-element, not the background */
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0; /* the arrow will always be at the bottom of teh .wrapper */
}
```

Comment: There is a slight modification in my question which i missed. I wan't to show the arrow relative to the li it is in .as shown in the picture arrow must be placed right below the active li

Comment: rereading my question,I have specified it in my first question itself..arrow must come right below the active li

Comment: Then apply the style from my answer to the active `li`, like this: `li.active::after {` (or whatever class it has). Don't forget to add `position: relative` to the `li`.